# Highcharts problems showing last values and close values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have troubles when I'm trying to use the Highcharts library, here is my code.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

var array = [{name: "Madrid Atocha Cer.", stop: "C", x: 0, y: 621.5},
{name: "Bif. Planetario", stop: "N", x: 3.5, y: 573.4},
{name: "Madrid-Santa Catalina (APD)", stop: "N", x: 5.4, y: 571.1},
{name: "Villaverde Bajo", stop: "N", x: 7.3, y: 578},
{name: "Villaverde Alto", stop: "N", x: 10.2, y: 603.6},
{name: "Zarzaquemada", stop: "N", x: 13.3, y: 627.6},
{name: "Leganes", stop: "C", x: 15.8, y: 671.6},
{name: "Parque Polvoranca", stop: "N", x: 17.9, y: 665},
{name: "La Serna-Fuenlabrada", stop: "N", x: 19.8, y: 659.9},
{name: "Fuenlabrada", stop: "N", x: 21.4, y: 676.1},
{name: "Humanes", stop: "N", x: 25.4, y: 681.9},
{name: "Humanes Ag.Km. 25,3", stop: "N", x: 27.9, y: 682.5},
{name: "Griñon", stop: "N", x: 31.3, y: 673.6},
{name: "Illescas", stop: "C", x: 41, y: 584.6},
{name: "Villaluenga Yuncler", stop: "N", x: 52.3, y: 519.5},
{name: "Bargas ", stop: "N", x: 65.1, y: 504.3},
{name: "Villamiel Toledo", stop: "N", x: 74.4, y: 478.8},
{name: "Torrijos", stop: "C", x: 88, y: 527.7},
{name: "Erustes", stop: "N", x: 106, y: 556.5},
{name: "Montearagon", stop: "N", x: 120.9, y: 388.6},
{name: "Talavera Reina", stop: "C", x: 136.8, y: 369.5},
{name: "Calera-Chozas", stop: "N", x: 151.4, y: 361.4},
{name: "Oropesa de Toledo", stop: "C", x: 171.8, y: 354.2},
{name: "Navalmoral Mata", stop: "C", x: 203, y: 288.5},
{name: "Casatejada", stop: "N", x: 214.3, y: 270},
{name: "La Bazagona", stop: "N", x: 233.8, y: 243},
{name: "Monfragüe", stop: "N", x: 254.2, y: 411.5},
{name: "Monfragüe Ag.Km.4,4", stop: "N", x: 258.6, y: 428.4},
{name: "Plasencia", stop: "C", x: 270.5, y: 343.9},
{name: "Monfragüe Ag.Km.4,4", stop: "N", x: 282.4, y: 428.4},
{name: "Monfragüe Ag.Km.255,4", stop: "N", x: 285.1, y: 474.3},
{name: "Mirabel", stop: "N", x: 294.4, y: 483.1},
{name: "Casas de Millan ", stop: "N", x: 306.4, y: 429.8},
{name: "Cañaveral", stop: "N", x: 312.1, y: 366.7},
{name: "Rio Tajo", stop: "N", x: 325.9, y: 226.9},
{name: "Casar de Caceres", stop: "N", x: 338.5, y: 350.1},
{name: "Caceres", stop: "C", x: 360.1, y: 456.3},
{name: "Aldea del Cano", stop: "N", x: 382.1, y: 360.1},
{name: "Aljucen", stop: "N", x: 425.9, y: 201.2},
{name: "Merida", stop: "C", x: 432, y: 217.4},
{name: "Calamonte ", stop: "C", x: 438.5, y: 227.3},
{name: "Almendralejo", stop: "C", x: 461.5, y: 347.6},
{name: "Villafranca Barros", stop: "C", x: 475.6, y: 410.8},
{name: "Los Santos Maimona", stop: "C", x: 488.7, y: 551},
{name: "Zafra Feria", stop: "C", x: 495.8, y: 522.5},
{name: "Zafra", stop: "C", x: 497.1, y: 520.5},
{name: "Km. 86,7 (40103)", stop: "N", x: 518.6, y: 583.8},
{name: "Llerena ", stop: "C", x: 537.5, y: 633.7},
]

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
    },

    series: [{
        data: array,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          rotation: -90,
          formatter: function ()
          {
            console.log(this);
            let value = this.x;
            return value;
          },
          align: 'left',
          style: {
            fontSize: '11px',
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.71)'
          },
          y: -5
        }
    }]
});
```

I have this array, but some of this data doesn't show up, the last value don't show and I don't know why. And if there are some data very close, the library won't draw the two point.

Could you know how I can draw all the data?.

Comment: I used your code here and it's ok.
Which value exactly does not appear?
What exactly is missing?

Comment: I tried it too: https://jsfiddle.net/qaw9fxob/1/
Everything seems fine to me. You might add a screenshot with an actual and an expected behavior, so we can understand your problem better.

Comment: the last value ({name: "Llerena ", stop: "C", x: 537.5, y: 633.7},) doesn't show in your test  jsfiddle.net/qaw9fxob/1

Comment: @Neskews this case

Comment: As @Neskews suggested everything seems to work as expected. I can see all the data on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You have two axes, X and Y.
If the X-axis values next to each other, it will display only one caption.
The chart does it to you have a readable graphics!

To you understand better, try to change X axis values of any item in your ARRAY to see if the desired data appears!

Answer (score 0):

As @GilbertoB.TerraJr. suggested, the chart automatically hides some of the points in order to make the chart better readable. However, you might have a look at it in full screen mode. This gives the chart enough space to show all the points.
[image]